# I got null from entity with @Data when I use @Requestbody

Tags: spring, lombok

I'm a junior web developer.
I don't understand why the authenticatedPgInfo return NULL
The follow is my simple test.

```
@RestController
public class InitController {
    @PostMapping("/test")
    public String test(@RequestBody AuthenticatedPgInfo authenticatedPgInfo) {
        return "";
    }
}
```

And

```
@Data
public class AuthenticatedPgInfo {
    private int code;
    private String message;
    private List<AuthenticatedPg> result;
}
```

If I change @Data to @Getter and @Setter, authenticatedPgInfo return null.
But, When I remove @Data, @Getter...(Lombok Annotation) and generate getter and setter, then It works!!

I don't understand why Lombok doens't work in this situation..
Can somebody help?
Thanks in advance.

test.json

```
{
  "result": [
    {
       "key": "rabbit",
       "value": "3"
    },
    {
       "key": "lion",
       "value": "1"
    }
  ],
  "message": "success",
  "code": 0
}
```

Comment: Please paste your request body json.

Answer (score 4):

OMG... I Made a biiiiiiiiiig mistake.
I didn't check `Enable annotation processing`in **IntelliJ**
All code all works as expected. Thank you guys!

Comment: Hahaha... Thats the best way to answer your own question! :)

Answer (score 2):

The [@Data annotation](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data) implicitly includes [@RequiredArgsConstructor](https://projectlombok.org/features/constructor), but not @NoArgsConstructor. Since Jackson needs a no argument constructor, then you would need to provide one. You can do that with Lombok by simply adding @NoArgsConstructor.

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class AuthenticatedPgInfo {
    private int code;
    private String message;
    private List<AuthenticatedPg> result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind Answer!.
But it doens't work,,,,

Answer (score 1):

Right now I reproduced the same example at my own - with `@Data` annotation only all works as expected.

To serialize json to the object, Jackson needs the default constructor of this object (i.e. without any parameters) or constructor with parameters and with `@JsonCreator` annotation.

By default Lombok creates the default constructor if any other does not exists. And Jackson use it. But maybe in your case something goes wrong, so you can create your DTO with `@JsonCreator` annotation, like this for example:

```
@Data
public class AuthenticatedPgInfo {
    private int code;
    private String message;
    private List<AuthenticatedPg> result;

    @JsonCreator
    public AuthenticatedPgInfo(@JsonProperty("code") in code,  @JsonProperty("mesage") String message, @JsonProperty("result") List<AuthenticatedPg> result) {
        this.code = code;
        this.message = message;
        this.result = result;
    }
}
```